# How to handle answers which are only CAS output?

Tags: discussion, flagging, answers, low-quality-posts

I'm quite uncomfortable with the fact that there are many answers by specific users (especially in the "integration"-tag where I spent most of my time here) which are clearly pure CAS output. On top of that this fact is 1.) not even marked  and 2.) horribly formatted which annoys me even more. Also this users where told many times that this is not an appropriate style of answering but this didn't lead to any change in their behaviour. 
Personally,  I would tend to delete such answers and also sanction the poster if he gives this kind of answers frequently. But maybe there are better solutions for that kind of problem, but I'm curious how you are thinking about that. 
As related question: Should I flag this kind of answers?

Comment: Related older posts: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19548/answers-composed-entirely-mechanically-e-g-by-computer-algebra-systems and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21274/users-providing-only-answers-in-maple

Comment: I do not think this really is a duplicate, as the emphasis is quite different.

Comment: More related: [How to deal with users consistently posting low quality answers](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/18918) and [Follow up to 'Users who consistently post low-quality answers'](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/21005)

Comment: Another issue i have is that one of this users have a reputation of more then 10k which give him especially in the eyes of some not so experienced participants an image which he may not deserve

Comment: I vote for reopening because this topic becomes more and more urgent. the user in question has 16k and still gives loads of wrong, useless or misleading answers. i think their is an urgent need for a solution to this problem

Comment: @tired I do not get what you are trying to achieve with the reopening of the duplicate. If you disagree it is a duplicate, explain the difference. If not, why reopen it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Downvote
2. Flag as Very Low Quality

Also, since you'll be adding flags to the system, don't forget to

3. Participate in [Review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review) to help take the trash out.

(You don't get to review your own flags, this is just a general remark about keeping the balance between creating and resolving flags.)

Comment: A question regarding flagging for VLQ: Is the flag handled by diamond moderators or by reviewers of the low-quality queue or both? The reason I'm asking is that I've had such a flag declined (as opposed to disputed).

Comment: And a related question: Is there consensus among moderators that answers only containing CAS output should be deemed helpful and that the answer should be purged?

Comment: @DanielR There is no consensus among anyone about anything. This is why we vote.

Comment: Strongly disagree with flagging/deleting these answers in many cases.  Answers should only be deleted if they are not actually answers at all or are so poorly written that they are incomprehensible; answers that are merely _bad_ answers are exactly what the downvote button is for.  If the question is clearly asking only about _how_ to derive the answer, then delete away, since such an answer isn't actually addressing the question.  But in many cases the intent of the question isn't so clear.