# Declined VLQ flag for an answer with CAS generated output

Tags: discussion, answers, flagging, low-quality-posts

Several hours ago, I flagged [an answer consisting entirely of SymPy code](//math.stackexchange.com/a/2725427/290189) (at [its second version](//math.stackexchange.com/revisions/df79e543-50c4-4827-b30b-e17a7986b074/view-source)) for "Very Low Quality" according to the procedures in the accepted answer of a meta question: *[How to handle answers which are only CAS output?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21942/290189)*.

In a [subsequent Low Quality review](//math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/990251), four out of the five reviewers voted to delete this answer.

Why is my flag declined?  Should I flag this again as "in need of moderator intervention" with the URL of the linked meta question?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: The answer now is not only CAS output (it seems it was when you flagged). That said, I still think the answer is pretty poor (yet not because it uses a CAS).

Comment: Maybe I'm just soft today, but I thought it didn't quite make the _very_ low quality bar.